# Moving LetsEncrypt SSL certs from one NginX server to another NginX server

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy

I'm running a Reverse Proxy Server (RPS) using NginX.  It is working fine for forwarding traffic to my sites which are not using SSL.  However, I just configured a new NginX web server with LetsEncrypt certs and my RPS is not working for that server.  I've researched the issue and it appears I need to copy the SSL certs from the web server to the RPS and reference them in the server block on the RPS for that webserver:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name mynew.Web.com;
   return 301 https://mynew.Web.com$request_uri;
 }

server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name mynew.Web.com;
   ssl_certificate  /path/to/your/certificate;
   ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/your/certificate/key; 
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
...}
```

If only copying files from one server to another, that I understand, but are SSL files special and need to be copied or backed-up and then restored using any special procedures?  For example, I worrying about permissions,...

So my question is, How do I copy the SSL certs from the webserver to the RPS?

Thanks...RDK

Comment: Why don't you let the reverse proxy handle the SSL termination and let it get the certificates directly?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure how that would work, since the LetsEncrypt certbot can't get the the server to verify the ownership.

Comment: for the reverse proxy it is enough to use a ssl certificate that is even invalid. nginx reverse proxy does not check for a valid one by default. so,  imho it feels like a [x and y problem](https://faq-database.de/doku.php?id=en:x-and-y-problem) so, what is the real issue you having?

Comment: I've updated my posting to clarify my question.  What I want to know is how to copy the SSL certs from the web server to the Reverse Proxy Server...